# materialize: autocomplete input moves content down

Tags: jquery, css, input, autocomplete, materialize

I'm using the autocomplete input of materialize but I've noticed that the content is moved down when I do the search, I've try to use position absolute property but it doesn't work, it just makes the content enter on the input, what should I do?

this is my code

```
<div class="input-field col s12 m4 l4 xl4">
      <input type="text" id="servicios" name="servicios" class="autocomplete">
      <label for="servicios-input">Servicios</label>
       </div>
       <div class="input-field col s12 m2 l2 xl2">
           <button class=" btn_edit_continue waves-effect waves-light btn" type="button" name="action" id="agregarServicio">Agregar</button>
       </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved it, the autocomplete dynamic ul has a static position settled by default, just set it to absolute and the problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

the only change you need to make is in your .css file, you have to add the property `position: absolute !important;` to the "dropdown-content" class.

you do not need to change the other files.

See the example bellow:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input').autocomplete({
    data: {
      "Apple": null,
      "Microsoft": null,
      "www.victorhnogueira.com.br": null,
      "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
    },
    limit: 10, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
    onAutocomplete: function(val) {
      // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
    },
    minLength: 1, // The minimum length of the input for the autocomplete to start. Default: 1.
  });
});
```

```css
/*THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED TO ADD TO YOUR CODE*/

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-field col s12">
  <input type="text" id="input" class="autocomplete" />
  <label for="inputDeBuscaDeProduto">search</label>
</div>
<div class="red">div bellow</div>
```